# VB.net programming in alphabets

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox2.text and I declare this as a string namely myletters and I also have a label36.text and I also declare this as a string namely patterns.

I will only input on the textbox is letters from "a" to "z" only and the reason why there is a label36 is that when I put the same letter again it will show an error message.

This is my code so far.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
  Dim patterns As String
  patterns = Label36.Text
  Dim myletters As String
  myletters = TextBox2.Text
  Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myletters, patterns)
  If Regex.IsMatch(patterns, myletters) Then
    MsgBox("You already typed this letter.")
  Else
    Label36.Text = Label36.Text + myletters + ","
  End If
End Sub
```

What use on the top is my code so far that will show error if I already put a same letter again and give this if I don't put the same letters.

Example Output:

Set A: a,b,c,d,e

Now here is my questions.

1) How can i input my first letter without following a comma?

Example:
a

But my output is
Example:
a,

2) How can i set my textbox to the maximum of input of just 1 letter?

3) How can i put commas in right time and format?

Example 1:
a
Example 2:
a,b

But my example is
Example 1:
a,
Example 2:
a,b,

4) How can i arrange the alphabet letters in the right positions?

Example 1:
a,z

If i will input "x" the output must be

Example 2:
a,x,z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting quite a few changes, although more or less easy:

"2) How can i set my textbox to the maximum of input of just 1 letter?"

```
TextBox2.MaxLength = 1
```

(Or by affecting the `MaxLength` property from the `Properties Panel` on the `Design View`)

The other 3 questions are answered with an updated version of the `else` in your code.

```
myletters = myletters.ToLower() 
If Regex.IsMatch(patterns, myletters) Then
    MsgBox("You already typed this letter.")
Else
    If (Label36.Text.Trim.Length > 0) Then
        Label36.Text = Label36.Text & "," & myletters

        Dim allLetters() As String = Label36.Text.Split(",")
        Array.Sort(allLetters)

        Label36.Text = ""
        For Each leter As String In allLetters
            Label36.Text = Label36.Text & leter & ","
        Next
        Label36.Text = Label36.Text.Substring(0, Label36.Text.Length - 1).ToLower() 'To delete the last ","
    Else
        Label36.Text = myletters
    End If
End If
```

Comment: @CrixalisPaul You are welcome. If you think that this is the right answer, please award it. Also bear in mind that your question/answer you get should be helpful for other people so, in the future, please write down a more generic question.

Comment: Sir one more question, I just wanna ask if I will input capital letter the code accepts it, how can i prevent that.

Comment: @CrixalisPaul I am not sure if I got your point: you mean that you want all the displayed text to be small caps, no matter what the user inputs?

Comment: @CrixalisPaul if you want what I said (Label36 always showing small caps), just include Label36.Text = Label36.Text.ToLower() put it after all the label modifications have been performed (at the end of "Private Sub Button3_Click")

Comment: If i will input "A" it will turn to "a" and it will happen in any letters. but if I will input "A" it will convert to "a" and transfer to the label but first it must be pass to my condition that if the letter is already input then it will not be accepted. @varocarbas

Comment: @CrixalisPaul yes this is exactly what does .ToLower() but if you want also to ignore caps in the condition you have to put it at the start too. I have updated my code right now to deliver exactly what you want, please, take a look at it. As you can see, both the initial input (myletters) and the final output (Label36.Text) get the .ToLower to make sure that it always deals with small caps.

Comment: Sir i have a new question please answer it. @varocarbas

Comment: @CrixalisPaul last one, OK? You have to understand that I am not here to solve your problems, but to give you some generic help which might contribute to help you grow as a developer and, mainly, help others. You shouldn't have posted a so specific question in a first place and, afterwards, you shouldn't keep asking specific problems, but understanding and extracted as much information as possible from my code. OK. What is the question?

Comment: @CrixalisPaul I have answered already to your question. Please, get all this information (and better the way to face this kind of problems), do some research, some trial error, etc. and ask questions just when you don't see the solution in any way. Asking for so specific solutions for so easily solvable problems does not help you to learn at all. Please, understand my point and don't ask me again questions on these lines (= easily solvable with A BIT of effort).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you store your letters in a string array instead of a string, like this:

```
Dim myLettersArray As String() = New String() {"a", "b", "c"}
```

By using `String()` as the type, you can loop through your letters, like this:

```
For Each letter As String In myLettersArray
    ' Do something with letter
Next
```

To force your input text box (`TextBox2`) to only allow a single character, then you can use the `MaxLength` property of the `TextBox` set to, like this:

```
TextBox2.MaxLength = 1
```

Note: For more information read [TextBox.MaxLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength.aspx) documentation.

To sort (read: alphabetize) your letters, all you need to do is call `Sort()`, like this:

```
Array.Sort(testArray, StringComparer.InvariantCulture)
```

Finally, your output issues with the comma stem from the fact that you are appending the comma instead of prepending the comma, like this:

```
Dim counter As Integer = 1
For Each letter As String In myLettersArray
    ' Check if this is the first letter
    If counter = 1 Then
        Label36.Text = Label36.Text & letter
    Else
        Label36.Text = Label36.Text & ", " & letter
    End If

    counter = counter + 1
Next
```